# How to show nested Rectangle in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to show the nested **Rectangle** with parent child replationship.
[Here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html) is one D3 example with using circle. I tried to convert this with rect but not Successied.
Please help.

Comment: This is using the circle packing layout -- there is no rectangle packing layout. To show that, you would have to implement the layout yourself.

Comment: I think so. Ok thank u for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `circle` by `rect` and changing the attributes to have `height` and `width` instead of `r` can do the trick.

You also have to edit the css and translate the rectangles as they are not aligned by their center.

I could only get squares but it can be a good lead: http://bl.ocks.org/ChrisJamesC/8914147

**Relevant code:**

Code necessary to add/edit in the gist you provided as an example.

CSS:

```
rect {
  fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);
  fill-opacity: .25;
  stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.leaf rect {
  fill: #ff7f0e;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
node.append("rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(-" + d.r + ",-" + d.r + ")";})
  .attr("width", function(d) { return 2*d.r; })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return 2*d.r; });
```

[image: Example of pack with squares]

Comment: A better choice for the length of the sides may be `Math.sqrt(2*r*r)` (square inside the circle). This avoids overlap between neighbouring squares.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is superb, Rectangles are overlapping but nice. Thank you again.